# What is the pressure in the walls of a cylinder container

Tags: forces, pressure, fluid-statics

So, the equation for pressure is $p=F/A$.
I saw in a video that the pressure exerted in an area is the same as that exerted on the walls of a container.
So to find out the pressure exerted on the cylinder walls I need to know the area of the base of the top of the cylinder.
The radius of the base of the top is $1.85$ centimeters.
The equation to calculate the area is $(\pi r^2)$. Then, $\pi \cdot 1.85^2$, with give me $10.75210086\ cm^3$.
I put this information on the pressure equation p = 1 Newton / 10.75210086 cm³, that give me $0.09300507994\ Pa$.

The steps that I make is correct and the result is the right one?
So how does it work?, in the sense, that I don't put the height of the cylinder nowhere, and from what I said earlier, about the pressure on the walls, is it really exercised evenly across the cylinder wall? even if the height of the cylinder is large?.

Comment: Where does the $1\mathrm{N}$ come from?

Comment: Is just a value for Force in p=F/A

Answer (score 0):

I think you are little confused as to how pressure works. Let me try and clear things up.

A cylinder contains a fluid (gas or liquid, here of zero density$^!$). The **outside** pressure is considered negligible ($\approx 0$) A weightless piston, perfectly sealed, closes it off:

[image: Pressure]

A force $F$ acts on the piston, which has cross-section
$A$.

The pressure inside the container, transmitted in all directions, is given by:

$$p=\frac{F}{A}$$

The force exerted on any part of the walls is:

$$F(S)=pS$$

where $S$ is the surface area of that part of the cylinder wall.

$^!$ If the density of the fluid is non-zero the hydrostatic pressure needs to be taken into account.

If the density of the fluid is $\rho$ then for a layer at distance $h$ from the piston then Pascal's Law tells us the hydrostatic pressure $p_h$ is given by:

$$p_h=\rho gh$$

And the total pressure at that level will be:

$$p_t=\rho gh+\frac{F}{A}$$

Comment: Just a little question, what F(S) stand for? beacause i'm not american, so this could mean something different. Could mean function of surface area?

Comment: I'm not American either LOL. Yes, it means *function of $S$*